# Работа с функцией time()

Tags: php, время

Всем доброго времени суток. У меня такой вопрос: как работать с функцией `time() php`? Вот например хочу сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на `submit` установить время, например, `30мин`, потом когда 30 мин пройдет выводить что-то не важно. Я думаю, вы поняли.

Comment: или так через 3 минуты обновлялось в базе поле

Comment: что бы через 30 минут что то вывело (кстати, где вывело? у пользователя?), нужно, что бы кто то с той стороны был готов принять. Обычно такие задачи решаются в паре с javascript + ajax.

Comment: да пользователя , ну а как ? php не вариант?

Comment: на php можно сделать, но только с пользовательской стороны придется также скрипт дописывать. Либо делать по comet технологии - когда клиент висит на сокете подключенным постоянно. Но вот только одна проблема - пхп обычно предназначен для "получил запрос, быстро сгенерировал страницу, отдал, следующий!". А выполнять долгую работу - это уже отдельная задача.

Answer (score 1):

На PHP не вижу смысла делать такое, лучше JavaScript: [тык](http://jsfiddle.net/xBzEW/2/)

Если вам все-таки приспичило на PHP, то привязываете к кнопке обработчик, посылающий запрос на сервер аяксом, потом в базу записываете значение, полученное через time(); на сервере, потом проверяете и так далее...
Чистым PHP справиться не получится (если только не обновлять постоянно страницу, чтобы проверить).